# Export ArrayPlot to pdf: Color outside frame

Tags: graphics, export, pdf-format

If I export an `ArrayPlot` to pdf, I frequently observe that the colored pixels do not end at the top frame edge. Here is an example:

```
data = Flatten[Table[{x, y, x + y}, {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}], 1];
plot = Block[{data2, xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax},
   data2 = 
    Reverse[Transpose[
      Partition[data[[All, 3]], 
       Length[DeleteDuplicates[data[[All, 2]]]]]]];
   xmin = Min[data[[All, 1]]];
   xmax = Max[data[[All, 1]]];
   ymin = Min[data[[All, 2]]];
   ymax = Max[data[[All, 2]]];
   Show[ArrayPlot[data2,
     ColorFunction -> "M10DefaultDensityGradient",
     PlotRangePadding -> None,
     FrameTicks -> All,
     DataRange -> {{xmin, xmax}, {ymin, ymax}}],
    PlotRange -> {{xmin, xmax}, {ymin, ymax}}]];
Export["plot.pdf", plot]
Export["plot.png", plot, ImageResolution -> 500]
```

The png export as well as the graphics in the notebook look fine:

[image: png]

Here is zoom-in of the top-left corner:

[image: png_zoom]

However, the pdf export has some color outside the frame:

[image: pdf_zoom]

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Simplest thing might be to turn the frame off.

Comment: But I want to have a frame with ticks. Maybe I don't understand your suggestion.

Comment: PDF export is terrible. One thing to do is to hide the error with FrameStyle -> Directive[Gray, Thickness[Large]]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that is also not possible for me. The line width of the frame should be consistent with other graphics and cannot be changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pdf export is running into problems because the `PlotRange` you are using is cutting off half of each cell in the outside perimeter in your array. You can see even more vividly that *Mathematica*'s pdf handling is not very good at dealing with this by exporting and then importing the image:

```
ImportString[ExportString[plot, "PDF"], "PDF"][[1]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Here it just gives up completely on trying to properly trim the plot.

The simplest solution is just to use `PlotRange -> All` if you don't actually need to cut off the cells on the perimeter. If you do need to cut them off, you could double the size of your array and do the trimming yourself.

Double the size of the array by converting each element to four elements, and then remove the outer border:

```
data3 = ArrayFlatten[Transpose[Table[data2, 2, 2], {3, 4, 1, 2}]][[2 ;; -2, 2 ;; -2]];
```

Make the `ArrayPlot` with the appropriate `DataRange`:

```
plot = ArrayPlot[data3, ColorFunction -> "M10DefaultDensityGradient",
  DataRange -> {{xmin + 1/4, xmax - 1/4}, {ymin + 1/4, ymax - 1/4}}, 
  PlotRange -> All, FrameTicks -> Table[Range[0, 10], 4], PlotRangePadding -> None
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now when exporting and importing, we see that the borders are respected:

```
ImportString[ExportString[plot, "PDF"], "PDF"][[1]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Quite a hack but it works. Thanks.